# Angular: Print out keyvalue pair stored in array

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, key-value

In my Angular project I fetch data from a backend that is not sorted. The data comes in keyvalue-pairs in JSON-format.
Today I just use the keyvalue pipe for spliting keys and values to 2 columns. I still want to do that but I want the data to be ordered in a specific order. I choose to use an array for putting the data in the right order. (custom pipe) The problem is that I do not know how to get the elements of the keyvalue-pairs that are stored in this array. Right now it just prints out [Object object]. Is there another pipe or something that I could use to get the data?

Right now my code looks liek this:

```html
    <tr *ngFor="let f of mydata$ | async | custompipe | keyvalue">
            <td class="key">{{ f.key | titlecase }}:</td>
            <td class="value">{{ f.value }}</td>
          </tr>
```

Edit:
  myData$ is an Observable that is getting its data from a redux store.

My pipe has a transform that returns an array with keyvalues, or to be more specific an interface with keys and values.

```js
transform(input: any): myKeyValueInterface[] {
    let output: myKeyValueInterface[] = [];
    for (const key in kundinfo) {
      if (kundinfo.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + ': ' + kundinfo[key]);
        const newElement: myKeyValueInterface= {key, value: input[key]};
        output.push(newElement);
      }
    }
    return output;
  }
```

Comment: Can you show how `myData$` is setup, and what the data coming from `myData$` looks like

Comment: myData$ is an Observable that is getting its data from a redux store

Comment: Yes... That's not particularly descriptive, unfortunately. You've not shown the relevant code, or what custompipe is. As things stand there's not enough information for people to help you out with your question I'm afraid.

Comment: your `| custompipe` has something wrong, and not returning data back to component. thats why your `|keyvalue` pipe not geting data enough

Comment: maybe something wrong. As I see it the problem is that I change the format from (what I guess is JSON) to an array. I do not know any other way to do it in order to specify the order of the keys. That is why I am asking for a way to access the elements of the array and do the keyvalue pipe on the members instead of the array members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keyvalue` pipe transforms Object or Map into an array of key value pairs.

You already transformed the input to an array with your custom pipe, so you should just remove the `keyvalue` pipe and it should work.

```
<tr *ngFor="let f of mydata$ | async | custompipe">
    <td class="key">{{ f.key | titlecase }}:</td>
    <td class="value">{{ f.value }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Oh, sometimes the solutions are easy. Thank you, that solved the problem for me.